# Is nonemptiness and boundedness of the subdifferential $f$ imply convexity $f$?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Is inverse of following theorem correct? that's mean, if $\partial f(x)$ is nonempty and bounded, then $f$ is convex?

Let $f:E \longrightarrow (-\infty , \infty]$ be a proper function,  and assume that $ x\in int(dom(f))$. Then $\partial f(x)$ is nonempty and bounded.

Comment: It should work if you add that $dom(f)$ is convex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Take
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if $x$ is integer}\\
+\infty & \text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $\partial f(x) = \{0\}$ for all $x\in dom(f)$.